# How do you include a command in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, command, chatbot

I'm creating a smart Chatbot. That part of information is irrelevant, however. What I'm trying to do is call on an instruction from within a dictionary - I'll show you:

```
dictionary = ["command1": "print("I just called command1!")]

dictionary["command1"]
```

Sort of like that. Obviously you cannot do that. I want to be able to have a dictionary of different commands which will run when you use dictionary[whatever_command you want_in_here]

Do you see what I mean?

I could use functions, but clearly that would take up a whole lot of space and lots of code which I cannot afford when there are so many responses in my Chatbot.

I really need to know how to do this in a simple way.

Answer (score 6):

Store instructions as anonymous functions:

```
dictionary = {
    "command1": lambda: print("I just called command1!"),
    "command2": lambda: print("I just called command2!")
}

command = input('Enter command: ')
dictionary[command]()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. The only problem is when I try print(dictionary[command]) is that it prints it then repeats None after it, like it also searched for something else apart from the lambda...

Comment: @ShabbyCat because the dictionary entry **is** the call to print. You should not add another print; and every action can replace the print

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to print strings, you're much better off doing something like:

```
dictionary = {"command1": "I just called command1!"}
print(dictionary["command1"])
```

but if you need to parse actual functions, you can, as @Uriel Eli said in the other answer, using a lambda.

```
mylist = []
dictionary = {"command1": lambda: print("I just called command1"), "command2": lambda: mylist.append("Here's an appended string!")}

dictionary["command1"]()
dictionary["command2"]()
```